# Memory models for assembly libraries for Turbo C

Tags: assembly, c

Turbo C follows the [Intel Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model) where in Tiny, Small and Compact models calling a function is near but in Medium, Large and Huge models calling a function uses far calls.

If I want to develop a Turbo C library using assembly, is there a way to make this library functional for all memory models? My problem is that functions in the library will return control using either RETN or RETF - and in either way they will malfunction in half of the memory models.

Is there a method to detect memory model from within the program, so as to notify the function in some way and make it decide between RETN and RETF?

Comment: Simply no. The issue is due basic 8086 workings. No (runtime) information about the type of a call taken is recorded on stack (or anywere else). Code has to be assembled specific for near or far calls. That's why (back then) every library was delivered in every (useful) fashion.

Comment: My guess is that you would have to use NEAR and SHORT jumps for all models and keep the code restrained. NEAR and SHORT jumps cause the IP to be updated while FAR jumps cause CS and IP to be updated." So, even using JMP will change the instruction at compile time. Other things to consider is self modifying code, store function data on stack or use batch files to compile in different models etc.

Comment: Not exactly "runtime" per se, I would not be surprised if there is some internal compile time defined STRING for the model being used. I remember vaguely such a thing for putting FAR or not into variables. If you manage to use it from asm....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a surefire way to detect the memory model being used at run-time, or even adjust code post-build in an object during linking. Libraries were provided in multiple variants, one for each supported memory model.

It is however possible to write code which will adjust to different memory models at build time, so a single assembly file can be used to produce all the required object file variants. In your procedure declarations, you can write

```
MYPROCEDURE proc DIST
```

where `DIST` is a macro you define as `NEAR` or `FAR` depending on the memory model (either detected, or specified by flags you provide when building all the variants of your library), and then the assembler will generate `RETN` or `RETF` as appropriate. You can also get the assembler to adjust `CALL` sites by declaring the external symbols appropriately each time (`extrn MYPROCEDURE:DIST` for TASM).

You will also need to handle segment registers differently in some cases (at least in the tiny memory model).

If you want to handle C calling conventions, things get a little more complex, especially if you need to handle pointers passed as arguments — their size will change depending on the memory model.

See [Ralf Brown’s AMISLIB](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html) for one such implementation.

Comment: Good answer. Usually it should be able to make segment registers handling agnostic. What's more relevant may be parameter passing, as pointer handling can vary according to memory model, which leads to a different stack layout and necessary handling differences (loading segment registers as well, etc.)

Comment: @Raffzahn: Memory model affects the size of pointers declared *without qualifiers*, but even when using small/medium model it's often useful to have a few pointers which are qualified `far` and can be used to access memory outside the main 64K.

Answer (score 6):

Given a function declaration like

```
void far copyAnywhere(void far *dest, void far *src, unsigned len);
```

it will be usable from within any memory model except `huge`.  If called from within e.g. small model code, passing non-qualified pointers, the generated machine code would look something like (arguments are pushed right to left)

```
; Set up argument len
push [len]
; Set up argument src
push ds
push [src]
; Set up argument dest
push ds
push [dest]
; Do the call, pushing both CS and IP
push cs
call _copyAnywhere ; Just pushes IP
```

The effect of memory models is to determine whether functions and pointers default to being `near` or `far`, but explicit `far` qualifiers can be used to handle cases contrary to that default.

Comment: Ah yes, so one could write all the assembly-language functions assuming far pointers and far calls, and declare them appropriately in the C-language headers... (At some cost in stack usage however.)

Comment: @StephenKitt: Also at cost--sometimes significant and sometimes not--of having to deal with objects being in different segments.

Comment: Yes, indeed. In development terms, for a library capable of supporting far models, you’d need to write the code for that anyway... The cost here is really that nothing can be optimised for smaller memory models.

Comment: It might also be workable to put a far call wrapper around code written to use near natively, then use different link-time bindings to call either the near or far entry point depending on the memory model of the calling code, via macros in the include file for your library.  This of course only works if the library is capable of working internally using near calls (i.e. it doesn't need to access data passed by the caller via far pointers).

Answer (score 5):

You can't really detect the memory model the C code was compiled with at runtime.  I suppose you check some sort of variable that indicates what model was used but you'd be constantly testing it in your assembly code making your code horribly inefficient. A much better way to handle multiple memory models with a library is to assemble a separate version of each function for each memory model.  Fortunately this doesn't mean you need write a separate function for each memory model.  You can use certain features of your assembler, assuming you're using TASM or other MASM derived assembler, so that you only write each function once.

### Handling far and near RET

The specific problem of RETN or RETF can be handled more or less automatically.  Normally you would just use the RET instruction, and the assembler will automatically pick the correct near or far return instruction based on how the procedure you use them in is defined.  For example:

```
nearproc PROC   NEAR
    ret               ; generates opcode C3, near RET
nearproc ENDP

farproc PROC    FAR
    ret               ; generates opcode CB, far RET
farproc ENDP
```

### The .MODEL directive

Normally if you don't specify NEAR or FAR, the default is NEAR, but this can be changed by the .MODEL directive:

```
    .MODEL  SMALL
    .CODE
smallproc PROC
    ret               ; generates opcode C3, near RET
smallproc ENDP
```

```
    .MODEL  LARGE
    .CODE
largeproc PROC
    ret               ; generates opcode CB, far RET
largeproc ENDP
```

### Specifying a calling convention

The .MODEL directive can also set a default calling convention when using the assemblers facilities for handling arguments to functions:

```
    .MODEL  COMPACT, C
    .CODE   

memcpy PROC dest:PTR, src:PTR, len:WORD
    push    cx

    IF      @DataSize       ; FAR data model

    push    ds
    push    es
    les     di, [dest]
    lds     si, [src]

    ELSE                    ; NEAR data model

    mov     di, [dest]
    mov     si, [src]

    ENDIF

    mov     cx, [len]
    cld
    rep movsb

    IF      @DataSize       ; FAR data model
    pop     es
    pop     ds
    ENDIF

    pop     cx    
    ret    
memcpy ENDP
```

Because the "C" language was specified with the .MODEL directive, the assembler handles generating the necessary prologue (`push bp` `mov bp, sp`) and epilogue (`pop bp`) and figures out where the arguments to function live on the stack relative to BP.  It automatically handles the fact that arguments will have different sizes depending on whether the code is using a near or far data model. It also automatically adds an underscore (`_`) to the name of the function, so the actual symbol being defined is `_memcpy`.

It doesn't however handle picking the instructions needed to load the arguments. As you can see this code is conditionalized on the `@DataSize` predefined symbol. This symbol is set to 0 for near data models and to 1 for far data models.  There's also `@CodeSize` predefined symbol you can use to determine the code model.

The .MODEL directive and the `@DataSize` and `@CodeSize` symbols it sets are all you need to not only ensure the correct RET instruction is used, but also to lets you handle the fact that your code will need to change in order accommodate the different memory models.

This is true whether you use the argument handling and automatic prologue and epilogue and other similar facilities of the compiler.  These can be a double edged sword though as the code that they generate isn't always optimal.  Instead of specifying a calling convention with the .MODEL directive you can also specify it on a procedure by procedure basis as an additional parameter in the PROC directive. Use NOLANGUAGE to tell the assembler not to do any of this code generation for the current procedure.

### How to pass a memory model on the command line

Now there's one problem left, how to tell the assembler which memory model to use.  The simple way would be define a symbol using the `/D` command line option, giving the name of the memory model you wanted:

```
ml /c /DMemModel=MEDIUM memcpy.asm
```

You could then use `MemModel` with the .MODEL directive:

```
    .MODEL MemModel, C
```

The problem with this is that only works with MASM 6.  With TASM or MASM 5 the `/D` option works differently. These assemblers would define `MemModel` as a symbol that's equal to the symbol `MEDIUM`, where as MASM 6 defines `MemModel` as a text macro that expands to `MEDIUM`.  Since TASM and MASM 5 would define `MemModel` as a symbol, you'll get an error because the .MODEL directive doesn't accept symbols.

Unfortunately, if you're using either of these older assemblers you need something more complicated.  The command line is almost the same, but note that the quotes are important:

```
tasm /ml /DMemModel="MEDIUM" memcpy.asm
masm /ml /DMemModel="MEDIUM" memcpy.asm;
```

(The `/ml` options are there so the assemblers define `_memcpy` in lower case, otherwise they'll convert it to uppercase `_MEMCPY`.)

For this work, you'll need this code at the start of your assembly source:

```
    IFIDNI  <"TINY">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  TINY, C
    ELSEIFIDNI  <"SMALL">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  SMALL, C
    ELSEIFIDNI  <"MEDIUM">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  MEDIUM, C
    ELSEIFIDNI  <"COMPACT">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  COMPACT, C
    ELSEIFIDNI  <"LARGE">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  LARGE, C
    ELSEIFIDNI  <"HUGE">, %MemModel
    .MODEL  HUGE, C
    ENDIF
```

To save having to having to repeat this code in every source file you can put it in an include file:

```
    INCLUDE memmodel.inc
```